# Sortable list in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a sortable list in angular js. What i want is i want to sort rows into columns and back. But after searching for hours, i couldn't find any.

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
        {{ category.title }}
        <ul ng-if="category.categories">
            <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories">
                {{ category.title }}
                <ul ng-if="category.categories">
                    <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories">
                        {{ category.title }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
```

I have these code and a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/fd178gxa/75/). I am new to angular js

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.sortable']);
    app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.categories = [
      { 
        title: 'Row 1',
        categories: [
          {
            title: 'Column 1',
          categories: [
              {
                title: 'element'
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            title: 'Column 2'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'Row 2',
        categories: [
          {
            title: 'Column 1',
          },
          {
            title: 'Column 2'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
});
```

Comment: Do you need to sort your categories by title?

Comment: @Senal no i want to sort row into column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS nested ul list and ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252097/angularjs-nested-ul-list-and-ng-repeat)

Comment: @melvin what do you mean by *sort row into column*, I saw that you are using ui-sortable module , do you want to sort your  order of `Row1` and `Row2` using the ui-sortable?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @AdeshKumar check my fiddle. I want rows to be sortable and able to drop inside columns

Comment: able to drop means

Comment: @AdeshKumar i need to move and place row1 to be under column1 using sortable

Comment: then why don't add it under column 1 by default

Comment: Can you please share output structure so that we understand what you exactly want?

Comment: it is in my fiddle @Ashutosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I  finally got the answer. I added Sortable options to the `ui-sortable`.

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="rows">
```

Then added sortable option to `sortableOptions`

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
     placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder',
   connectWith:'.elements',
   }
$scope.sortableElmOption = {
     placeholder: 'ui-sortable-placeholder',
   connectWith:'.rows',
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use orderby this way (in every ng-repeat) :

```
<li ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy:'title' ">
```

Let me know if its enough to work

Comment: I asked for ui-sorting not the one you mentioned